# Android navigation online drawer update of itmes

Tags: android, fragment, drawer, on-the-fly

I'm stuck at the point where I need to update items of the navigation drawer on the fly/online.

My navigation drawer is based on this tutorial
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

I want to update one item of the drawer depending on values stored in shared preferences. 
Actually I want to display either "my account" or "register".
To differentiate I'm storing a boolean value in the shared preferences if the user is logged in or not.
Now I'm checking this in the `getView()` API of the `CustomDrawerAdapter`.
By this the text is updated, but not immediately. Only after I call another drawer item and the related fragment is opened.

Here is the added code of getView():

```
    Boolean UserLoggedIn = helper.getUserLoggedInFromSharedPrefs();
    Log.d(TAG, "UserLoggedIn=" + String.valueOf(UserLoggedIn));     
    if (!UserLoggedIn) {            
        drawerItemList.set(1, new DrawerItem("Login", R.drawable.ic_launcher));         
    }
    else {          
        drawerItemList.set(1, new DrawerItem("My account", R.drawable.ic_launcher));            
    }
```

How can I update the drawer item "on-the-fly"?

Comment: Don't try to change Adapter's List in `getView()`. Change the List when the user logs in, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter.

Comment: Hi Mike, this is working. Thanks a lot!
Just need to find a proper way how to update from the login class/fragment the main activity.
At the moment I do the update in onDrawerOpened() and this is causing slight delay in updating the text.